# Build error in golang package compilation

Tags: go, db2, go-gorm

I'm designing an IBM DB2 warehouse database using Go ORM. I include the dependencies

`import (    _ "github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db"  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm" )`

and create the database

```
func Init() \*gorm.DB {

    db, err := gorm.Open("ibm_db", dbURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Error db init Database.init 19")
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    migrate(db)
    return db
}
```

but I receive this error:

```
Build Error: go build -o /home/t/skola/programmering/hackYourWorld/api/\__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l .

# github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db/api

/home/t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db@v0.4.2/api/api_unix.go:13:11: fatal error: sqlcli1.h: No such file or directory 13 | 
// #include \<sqlcli1.h\> |           ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~ compilation terminated. (exit status 2)
```

I'm running a ubuntu docker container with go1.18.1 and include the package according to the documentation: `go get -d github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db\`

I tried installing it but can't find any possible problem.

Comment: The sqlcli*.h files are present in the clidriver/include directory. Did you add a clidriver in your container and set the environment variables (e.g INCLUDE) as documented at https://github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db in the README.md section entitled "How to install in Linux/Mac"?